# Deny access from particular environments in node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Is it feasible to make access from particular environments, such as countries, operating systems, and browsers denied in Node.js and Express? I'm now constructing a web service, but must implement such filters before launching it for some reasons.

I use Node.js v0.10, Express v3.x, and would deploy on heroku. So here's my question:

- Is it feasible to implement such filters in my deploy environment, and if it is, how can I do?
- Is it feasible to implement such filters only on some specific services, such as comment sections?

I also wonder how secure and robust it can be to have access from those countries denied successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is not a heroku question, and in my humble opinion not a node nor javascript question well. This is more likely an http and/or tcp question).

You can filter by these, but beware: it is *not* secure at all.

- Detecting the user's country is usually done by ip (which you can get with `req.ip`) which is later converted to a location (with some ip/geo service, e.g. MaxMind).
- Detecting the browser is done with the User-Agent http header. This is accessible with `req.headers['user-agent']`.
- Detecting the OS is also done by parsing the user-agent header. There are other ways of doing this (passive os fingerprinting -- http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/) but these are probably not deploying on Heroku.

Note that in order to avoid filtering by country, the user can simply access your web server using a proxy in an allowed country. Also, since user-agent is a string the *client* sends, they can send whatever they want and fake any browser/os.

It really depends on how strict your "filtering security" requirements are.